# Creating a JPQL query in CrudRepository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to build a query that will return all the `ToDoItems` from passed `User` (want to pass logged in `User`) using `JPQL`.

Here is my stuff so far, don't know how to build it exactly:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

   @Query(" from User u ")
   public Iterable<ToDoItem> findAllToDosForLoggedInUser(@Param("user") User user);

}
```

Here are my entities (omitted setters and getters):
**ToDoItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TO_DO_ITEM")
public class ToDoItem extends BaseEntity {

   @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
   private String title;

   @Column(name = "COMPLETED")
   private boolean completed;

   @Column(name = "DUE_DATE", nullable = false)
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   protected Calendar dueDate;

   // a ToDoItem is only associated with one user
   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
   private User user;


   // JPA demands empty contructor
   public ToDoItem() {}

   public ToDoItem(User user, String title, Calendar dueDate) {
      this.user = user;
      this.title = title;
      this.dueDate = dueDate;
   }
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "USERS")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

   @Column(name = "USERNAME")
   private String username;

   @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
   private String password;

   @Column(name = "EMAIL")
   private String email;

   // user can have many ToDoItems
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems;

   // JPA demands empty constructor
   public User() {}

   public User(String username, String password, String email) {
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.email = email;
   }
}
```

Could someone also check if my entities are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query should like :

```
@Query(" select td from User u inner join u.toDoItems td where u = :user")
```

In your User entity your mapping should have the `mappedBy` attribute:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
private Set<ToDoItem> toDoItems;
```

Comment: IntelliJ higjlights User in that Query and says 'it cannot resolve that symbol' and I can't check it now if it works - is IntelliJ just wrong or it's not correct?

Comment: I have the 2016 version and i get a lot of wrong syntax errors in those queries.. its always best to run the code and see what happens